# Is variable length relationship is traversed in BFS manner in Neo4j?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, breadth-first-search

If we have the following graph:

[image]

And the following query:

```
MATCH (me)-[:KNOWS*1..2]-(remote_friend)
WHERE me.name = 'Filipa'
RETURN remote_friend.name
```

Is `"Dilshad"` guaranteed to be returned before `"Anders"`, in other words, is `:KNOWS*1..2` guaranteed to be traversed in BFS manner?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is DFS.

If you want to control this and more things about the traversal there is a path expander in the APOC library

https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-querying/path-expander/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there any place in the docs that says that variable length relations are traversed in DFS fashion.